# regex get everything after dot

Tags: regex

Need a help with a simple regex.
I need to remove everything before the first dot (including the dot)
Example:

```
Text-To-remove.Text.ToKeep.123.com
```

Should be:

```
Text.ToKeep.123.com
```

I tried `\.(.*)` but it keeps the first dot:

```
.Text.ToKeep.123.com
```

Please advice

Comment: You already have the value, it is in the first capture group. See the highlight in green at https://regex101.com/r/E0U2aC/1

Comment: What tool/language are you using? Please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses a positive lookbehind:

```regex
(?<=\.).*$
```

### Demo